# Umbraco 7 UmbracoViewPage could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have downloaded Umbraco 7.2.1
I have opened the website in Visual Studio 2012 and run it
It has succesfully compiled and I have run the setup, building the database, and logging in for the first time to the admin panel.
On the first login a popup window says that "the server returns an error" without saying anything else.
So I stopped the site and I've tried to run it in debug mode, but it doesn't compile anymore
That's crazy, as I haven't touched anything...
It says:

The type or namespace name 'UmbracoViewPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f1b032e2\a66de32d\App_Web_macro.cshtml.a38a5b49.z6df839k.0.cs

I haven't found anything on internet, on support forum... nothing.

How can it be possible? 
Maybe the version 7.2.1 has too much bugs that should not yet be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the zip file download, it could be that you bin folder was cleaned during a rebuild in Visual Studio, visual studio cleans the folder for files during rebuilds, and pulls all the referenced libaries in to the folder.

One way to fix this is copying the bin folder to a lib folder and reference all the files using the project references.

Another possible issue is that the zip file wasn't unblocked in windows before being extracted.

I would recommend using the NuGet package if possible it makes the setup a lot easier.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/UmbracoCms/

And also makes it easy to update when the time comes.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, installed from NuGet it works perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear, I hope you will enjoy Umbraco it's a great CMS :-)